# Get daily user followers count with date in last 7 days in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a query to get (for the last 7 days) the daily count of user followers in SQL Server. I wrote this query, but it is not returning the expected output. Right now it returns the count, but it's not a correct data.

Here is my query and please tell me where my mistake is. I have 2 tables in the database, 1st is `user` and 2nd is `userfollowers`.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DateColumn, 
    uf.TotalCount 
FROM 
    (VALUES (0), (-1), (-2), (-3), (-4), (-5), (-6)) AS T(i)
OUTER APPLY 
    (SELECT 
         COUNT(UF.InsertDateTime) AS TotalCount
     FROM 
         userfollowers UF
     INNER JOIN 
         user U on U.UserId = UF.UserFollowerId
     WHERE 
         DATEDIFF(DAY, UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 
         AND UF.IsFollowed = 1 
         AND U.IsMUser = 1 OR U.IsFUser = 1) uf
```

Expected output:

```
DateColumn | Count
10-05-2017     8
09-05-2017    05
08-05-2017    20
07-05-2017    10
06-05-2017    30
05-05-2017    50
04-05-2017    50
```

This is the sample data from my database tables:

```
 UFID | UserId | UserFolloresId | IsFollowres | InsertDateTime
 1       1110          100             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
 2       1120          100             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
 3       1130          100             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500 
 4       1200          100             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
 5       1110          101             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
 6       1120          101             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
 7       1130          101             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500 
 8       1200          101             1        2017-05-10 11:26:27.500
```

This data shows this query with i want to get 8 count but i am getting 0. so i don't know where is my mistake any one know please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query,

```
;WITH [CTE_DATE]
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)  AS [DATE]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DD,-1,[DATE]) FROM [CTE_DATE] WHERE DATEDIFF(DD,[DATE],GETDATE()) <= 5
)

SELECT [DATE] ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                FROM userfollowers INNER JOIN [user] U on U.UserId = UF.UserFollowerId UF 
                WHERE CAST(UF.InsertDateTime AS DATE) = [DATE] 
                AND UF.IsFollowed = 1 and (U.IsMUser = 1 or U.IsFUser = 1)) AS TotalCount
FROM [CTE_DATE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want your `WHERE` clause to be:

```
       WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, UF.InsertDateTime, DATEADD(DAY, T.i, GETDATE())) = 0 AND
             UF.IsFollowed = 1 AND
             (U.IsMUser = 1 OR U.IsFUser = 1)
```

This fixes a logic error.  It might fix the results you are getting.

I would also write the logic as:

```
       WHERE CAST(UF.UF.InsertDateTime as DATE) = DATEADD(DAY, T.i, CAST(GETDATE() as DATE) ) AND
             UF.IsFollowed = 1 AND
             (U.IsMUser = 1 OR U.IsFUser = 1)
```

SQL Server will use an index when casting a date/time to a date, so this is sargable whereas your version is not.